# Table doesn't show up in ADO object

Tags: ado.net, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

I used SQL Server Management Studio to create 3 tables using SQL statements.

Then I attempted to create an ADO object in Visual Studio. The ADO wizard saw my database, but not the tables I created.

Is this because I need to somehow commit the changes I've made in Management Studio?
Or do I need to add some kind of prefix to the table names like:

```
CREATE TABLE mydb.Table1 ... ?
```

Or could this be a permissions thing?

Or am I not waiting enough time (1 min or so) for the ADO wizard to grab the table names from the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I guess when you script the creation of your tables (or anything else you're adding) you need to add this:

```
USE [Interview_MicahHoover]
GO
```

So much for relying on the ETL guy to set things up ;)

I figured this out by using the GUI to create the table, then right clicking on the new table in the left menu and saying 'CREATE TO ... clipboard', pasting into notepad, and looking at how the SQL Server Management Studio did it.